# What are the top three applications (in terms of number of citations) of the "reverse search" algorithm of David Avis?

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, applications, algorithms, polyhedra, convex-hull

I can see that this algorithm is quite popular, and that one of the original papers now has 820 citations on Google Scholar. However, what are the most highly cited applications of it?

If in Google Scholar I click on a paper about the reverse search algorithm, I can get a list of the papers that cited it, in order of most highly cited papers to least highly cited papers. For example: [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=4354690463473566057&as_sdt=5). However you can see in this case that the most popular works that cited the paper, are books or surveys that mention the paper (along with mentioning every other paper in the field), and so do not give any indication about the popularity of a specific application of the method itself.

It seems the answer to this question would best be given by experts in the field who would know how to immediately sift through those Google Scholar citations and pick out the ones that they know to be relevant. I ask the question here in case some of those experts may be in this Stack Exchange community.

Comment: You might want to try [other indexing tools](https://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/journals/dam/dam65.html) (3 down), for example clicking on magnifying glass [leads here](https://academic.microsoft.com/search?q=Reverse+Search+for+Enumeration.) as one of the choices. That doesn't make your *job* smaller but other tools (not GS) might give *better* results - for example the second link shows his paper, updates to it, then other papers derived from it. A *raw* [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=reverse+search+David+Avis+efficient+enumeration+vertices+polyhedra) leads to > 31K results. { :(